# How to use TEnumAsByte Unreal 4.22

Tags: c++, input, unreal-4, platformer

---

**The problem**

I am attempting to use a `TEnumAsByte` in one of my class headers:

I get compilation errors:

[image: Compilation errors.]

---

**Code sample**

I have included everything relevant to the member variable I am trying to create:

Header File:

```c
#pragma region Engine Includes

#include <Containers/EnumAsByte.h>

#pragma endregion

UCLASS( Blueprintable, ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
class PLATFORMER_API UGrappleAbilityComponent : public UActorComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

protected:
    // Begin AActor Interface //

    /** Called when play starts */
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    // End AActor Interface //

public:
    /** Determines what type of debug draw is used for the continuous grapple scanning */
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, EditAnywhere, Category = "Grapple Scan", meta = (AdvancedDisplay, DisplayName = "Grapple Cont Scan Debug Draw Type"))
        TEnumAsByte<EDrawDebugTrace::Type> m_GrappleScanDebugDraw;
}
```

Source File:

```c
UGrappleAbilityComponent::UGrappleAbilityComponent()
{
    PrimaryComponentTick.bCanEverTick = true;


    // Give an initial value to the debug draw mode for the continuous grapple scanning.
    m_GrappleScanDebugDraw = EDrawDebugTrace::None;
}

...

void UGrappleAbilityComponent::GrappleScanContinuous(FHitResult & OutHit)
{
    // Only scan if the player is not attached and their airbrake is not active
    if (!m_GrappleHook->IsAttached() && !m_OwnerCharacter->IsAirbrakeActive()) {

        // Increment the trace lerp value.  -   Then wrap the Trace lerp value back around to 0.
        m_GrappleScanTraceLerp += 0.1f;         if (m_GrappleScanTraceLerp > 1.f) { m_GrappleScanTraceLerp = 0.f; }

        // Calculate the proposed end point of the grapple.
        FVector EndPoint = m_StartPoint + m_StartPointDirection * m_GrappleCastDistance;
        float zOffset = FMath::Lerp(m_GrappleContScanLowHeight, m_GrappleContScanHighHeight, m_GrappleScanTraceLerp);
        EndPoint.Z += zOffset;

        // Perform the box traces.
        UKismetSystemLibrary::BoxTraceSingle(GetWorld(),
            m_StartPoint, EndPoint, m_GrappleContScanHalfSize, FRotator::ZeroRotator, 
            UEngineTypes::ConvertToTraceType(ECollisionChannel::ECC_GameTraceChannel5),
            false, {}, m_GrappleScanDebugDraw.GetValue(), OutHit, true);
    }
}
```

---

**Additional Info**

The compilation errors relating to the BoxTraceSingle call are irrelevant as they only occur due to the compilation errors with the TEnumAsByte. Aside from the `.GetValue()` call. Removing this still causes similar compilation errors however.

I can confirm this as, by looking at Epic's engine code, they use TEnumAsByte in *exactly* the way I have done here, aside from the `.GetValue()` call.

What the hell is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error C2653, the first one, says that `EDrawDebugTrace` isn't a class or namespace name, which is another way of saying (in this context) that the compiler has not yet seen a definition for `EDrawDebugTrace`. That's the root of your problem.

Error C2923 is telling you that you cannot use `EDrawDebugTrace::Type` as a parameter for the template `TEnumAsByte<>`. The *reason* you cannot use `Type` is because the compiler doesn't know what it is, since it's nested inside `EDrawDebugTrace` which the compiler *also* doesn't know about (because of the first error).

At this point in your code, the only `#include` you have [is for `TEnumAsByte<>` itself](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Containers/EnumAsByte.h). This header does not define `EDrawDebugTrace` (instead, it comes from [the `KismetSystemLibrary.h` header](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Classes/Kismet/KismetSystemLibrary.h)).

To fix this, you should include `KismetSystemLibrary.h` (or some other header that includes it indirectly) in your code before you try to use `EDrawDebugTrace`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!   It's interesting that it's so hard to diagnose that as an error when without including the header, the enum values within the namespace are visible.